# Thymeleaf expression to get list from yaml using text template mode

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf template resolver mode set to `TEXT`. I'd like to get `list` from that yaml file:

```
a: b
list:
   - el1
   - el2
   - el3
```

and simply rewrite these values exactly in the same form into another yaml file.

I tried to create Thymeleaf expression in `.template` file but nothing works. For property `a` - `[[#{a}]]` works fine in `.template` file.
Another option I tried was to change the list elements to comma separated values:

```
a: b
list:"el1,el2,el3"
```

and use `strings.arraySplit` but again that doesn't work.